# Open cart can't edit view

Tags: php, opencart

I'am trying to edit a file `view/common/home.tpl`, but I see no changes in the browser, I've tried to clear the `system/cache` - folder, but still no changes, if I edit the controllers, it will work fine, but can't edit the view files, any ideas?

Comment: Admin or catalog side?

Comment: Editing correct template? Not overwritten by any others?

Comment: Are you using VQMOD? if so clear the cache folder inside VQMOD.

Answer (score 0):

Few possible reasons:

1. If you are using vqmod to edit file, clear the vqmod cache be deleting files of `vqmod/vqcache` folder (if this is the reason,then also update your vqmod)
2. if this is catalog side, make user you are editing `home.tpl` of current theme

Easiest way of checking is to delete all the content of `home.tpl` directly and then home page should disappear.